# Convert JSON array field into a class object using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

There are about a dozen related questions, but none of them seems to apply for my case so I'll ask another one.

I want to convert an array field in a JSON to a Java class using GSON.

Convert this:

```
{ ...
  coordinates: [1,2,3],
  ...
}
```

To this:

```
class MyData {
    ...
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    final @NonNull Coordinates coordinates;
    ...
}

class Coordinates {
    final float x;
    final float y;
    final float z;

    Coordinates(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use a `JsonDeserializer<Coordinates>` but I'm getting the following error:

> JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 485 path $.data[0].placements[0].coordinates

I can use

```
class MyData {
    ...
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    final @NonNull List<Float> coordinates;
    ...
}
```

but then I need to manually build the `Coordinates` class.

Comment: In the coordinates json, you should specify which value is x, y, z. If you don't, how can Gson map these values to coordinate's fields? Thus, your `coordinates` property has a different data type comparing to your json.

Comment: I have no control over the JSON so I can't specify. I realize that I have to do the mapping, that's why I want to use a `JsonDeserializer`. My problem is how to get the array from the JSON into the deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor in your `Coordinates` class:

```
Coordinates(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

and a deserializer:

```
private static final JsonDeserializer<Coordinates> COORDINATES_DESERIALIZER
        = (je, type, jdc) -> {
            if (je.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray arr = (JsonArray)je;
                return new Coordinates(
                        arr.get(0).getAsFloat(),
                        arr.get(1).getAsFloat(),
                        arr.get(2).getAsFloat());
            } else if (je.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonObject obj = (JsonObject)je;
                return new Coordinates(
                        obj.get("x").getAsFloat(),
                        obj.get("y").getAsFloat(),
                        obj.get("z").getAsFloat());
            }
            return null;
        };
```

That needs to be registered in your `Gson` object:

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
       .registerTypeAdapter(Coordinates.class, COORDINATES_DESERIALIZER)
        .create();
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've tried this but the `JsonDeserializer` is not being called. I'm getting an error instead. From what I can understand, `JsonDeserializer`s are only called for `JsonElement`s but the value of the field is an array which for some reason is not considered as one.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I managed to find is to use post-processing on the JSON after deserialization as described [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/post-processing-on-gson-deserialization-26ce5790137d). It makes GSON call the `gsonPostProcess()` method on every class it deserializes and implements the `PostProcessable` interface.

Then I can use something like this:

```
class MyData implements PostProcessable {
    ...
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    final @NonNull List<Float> coordinatesData;
    final @NonNull Coordinates actualCoordinates;
    ...

    @Override
    public void gsonPostProcess() {
        if (coordinatesData == null || coordinatesData.size() < 3) {
            throw new JsonParseException("MyData must contain coordinates with at least 3 values");
        }

        float x = coordinatesData.get(0);
        float y = coordinatesData.get(1);
        float z = coordinatesData.get(2);

        actualCoordinates = new Coordinates(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Still hoping to get a better solution here.